# a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a code

```
image = Image.open(filename)    #opening the image
binary = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(message), 16))    #converting string into binary
binary = binary.append('1111111111111110')   #adding delimeter at the end 
binary = binary**.lstrip('0b')   #removing the starting ob of binary
```

............continue

and because of line 2 i am getting this error

**binary = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(message), 16))

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

i dont understand this error and nothing seems to work

Comment: Where is `message` assigned? [`hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) expects bytes, not a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `message` contains a string, but it needs to be a sequence of bytes. To encode a string into bytes, you can do something like this:

```py
message.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: encode function in python converts a string into hexadecimal (unicode) then should i remove binascii.hexlify because hexlify will also convert into string into hexadecimal?

Comment: Depends what you're trying to accomplish. From the perspective of function signatures, `hexlify` returns a value that is the same type as its parameter (they're both `bytes`), so you could get rid of it. My guess is that the encode method is what you actually want and you can get rid of `hexlify`, but I don't know what the end goal is.

Comment: Happy to help! Please mark my answer as accepted so people in the future know that it worked :)

Comment: sure that would be a great help for other beginners like me